# Using forloop to fix a value based on conditions in r

Tags: r, function, for-loop, dataframe, while-loop

I am trying to fix outliers in my data, and have converted data to a  structure organised like below in R.

company_1(a column from a dataframe) has 12 row data and every 6 row data refers to a period so there are 2 periods.

```
    company_1
1     123
2     0
3     567
4     0
5     987
6     678
7     657
8     567
9     543
10    345
11    2341
12    5432
```

**What I am looking for is**: for each column in my dataframe, I would like to fix 0 and values that larger than its standard deviation to its corresponding time period value(+ or - 6 row), and if that corresponding time period value is also an outliers, then it looks for the next(or previous) corresponding time period value until all corresponding time period value has been checked.

I have tried code below and the idea was to fill one column data into a matrix, then the first row would be the values of 6th and 12th,18th row of original column.

```
> sd.value <- as.numeric(apply(df,2, function(x) sd(x, na.rm = TRUE)))
> for(i in 1:dim(df)[2]){
>        for(j in 1:dim(df)[1]){
>          if(df[j,i] == 0 | df[j,i] >= sd.value[i]*3){
>            df[j,i] <- matrix(data = df[,i], nrow = 6, ncol = 2)[j,][matrix(data = df[,i], nrow = 6, ncol = 2)[j,]!=0 & matrix(data
> = df[,i], nrow = 6, ncol = 2)[j,] <= sd.value[i]*3][1] 
>          } else{
>            df[j,i] <- df[j,i]
>          }
>        }
>      }
```

matrix would be like this:

```
  [,1]   [,2]
[1,] 123  657
[2,] 0    567
[3,] 567  543
[4,] 0    345
[5,] 987 2341
[6,] 678 5423
```

But, this for-loop can only deal with the first 6 values. this is because, for example,  for the 8th row in the original column, it should check the 2nd row value in that matrix and determine if it need to be fixed. however, I do not know how to instruct R to 'check' the 2nd row of matrix while it comes to i = 8,14...

any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is your expected output? Confused because you aren't calculating standard deviation, your `sd.value` is equivalent to  `mean(df$company_1)`. So I'm not understanding what the "corresponding time period value" is.

Comment: @ waterling sorry, it should sd(), already corrected

Comment: @ waterling, the expected outcome is, take 2nd row(it is 0) in the column for example, to replace it by 8th vlaue if 8th value is not an outlier otherwise by 14th values. because 6 is a period, can I am trying to replace outliers to its "seasonal value"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following functions may be helpful to you.
fixCol is used to fix the values in a vector based on the conditions: 0 and values that larger than its standard deviation are defined as outliers. The outliers will be the replaced by the next non-outlier value corresponding time period value(+6 row). If no such non-outlier value exist, the outliers remain unchanged.

fixCol accepts a vector or a column of a data.frame as the input, and returns the fixed vector .

NB: the codes uses the package of dplyr and the chaining %>% to modify a data.frame. This is more efficient than for loop and is easy to understand.

Hope it helps!

```
library(dplyr)
# fill NA values using the new non-NA value
# the NAs after the last non-NA values are unchanged
fillNaUseNextNonNa <- function(vecTest)
{
    vecPre <- rep(vecTest[!is.na(vecTest)], diff(c(0,which(!is.na(vecTest)))))
    vecNew <- c(vecPre, rep(NA, length(vecTest)-length(vecPre)))
    return(vecNew)
}

# use the closet precedent non-na value to replace. if not found, use the closet following non-na value
fillNaBackward <- function(vecTest)
{
    if(all(is.na(vecTest))) stop("All values are NA or invalid")
    # (firstNonNaValue, vecTest)
    vecTest <- c(vecTest[which(!is.na(vecTest))[1]], vecTest)
    vecAfterTest <- rep(vecTest[!is.na(vecTest)], diff(c(which(!is.na(vecTest)), length(vecTest)+1)))
    # vecNew <- c(vecPre, rep(NA, length(vecTest)-length(vecPre)))
    return(vecAfterTest[-1])
} 

# fix the values in a vector based on conditions in R
fixCol <- function(vecNum){
    sdValueTri <- sd(vecNum, na.rm = TRUE)
    # vecValid <- (vecNum == 0 | vecNum >= sdValueTri)
    dfTmp <-data.frame(num = vecNum, valid = !(vecNum == 0 | vecNum >= sdValueTri))
    # group

    # then fix
    dfTmp <- dfTmp %>% 
        group_by(group=row_number()%%6) %>%
        mutate(numNew = ifelse(valid, num, NA)) %>%
        mutate(numNew = fillNaBackward(numNew)) %>%
        mutate(numNew = ifelse(is.na(numNew), num, numNew)) %>%
        ungroup() %>%
        select(numNew)
    return(dfTmp$numNew)
}

# example
df <- data.frame(company_1 = c(123,0,567,0,987,678,657,567,543,345,2341,5432))
df <- df %>% mutate(company_1_fix = fixCol(company_1))
# df$company_1_fix
# 123 567 567 345 987 678 657 567 543 345 987 678
```

Comment: Looks good @Huanfa Chen . But why 2341(11st) and 5432(12th) aren't being replaced by 987(5th) and 678(6th) since they

Comment: Here I only used the search direction of +6 rows. 11st and 12th elements donot have next non-NA values, so they are unchanged.

Comment: Here I only used the search direction of +6 rows. 11st and 12th elements donot have next non-NA values, so they are unchanged. If you would like to use the bi-directional search (+6 or -6 rows), it is better to define clearly which one to use if both values are usable. And, it is not difficult to revise the code accordingly.

Comment: @ Huanfa Chen. Can you please set the bi-directional search tactics in your code and let R to pick up the first usable value. By doing so, I guess these two large values can be well fixed. Also, I am quite new to R programming, and your code seems very neat, so I don't know how to revise it. Cheers

Comment: @henry I am glad to revise the code. Could you please clarify this problem: which one to use if both values (+6 row and -6 row) are usable?

Comment: thanks.  If both values (+6 or -6) are available, R picks the -6 value. I guess it helps to fix **(a)** bi-directional search(as you suggested) . **b** the 11(st) and the 12(nd) row will be able to be replaced by their previous counterparts **c** if there are multiple +6 or -6 values (as row goes to 24,36) , R will be able to choose the -6 one. Please correct me if i am wrong and hope it did not confuse you.

Comment: To be more clear: suppose the elements of 6,12,18,24,36 are 1,NA,NA,2,3. NA means invalid, and the other figures are valid. Which one should be used to replace the 18th element, the value of 6th (1) or 24th (2)?

Comment: Good question. But I guess when such a scenario happens, the 18th and the 12nd value will be all set to the 6th value Because the 12nd searches for the 6th (for imputation) while the 18th searches for the 12nd value. hope I understand it correctly .

Comment: perhaps, letting 0 or outliers being replaced by the mean of all corresponding non-outliers value(s) is more easy to do in bi-directional search.  simple and effective. what do you think :)

Comment: Edited. A new function has been added.

Comment: sorry to interrupt you. I've been triying to figure out your solution step by step,and didn't quite understand how you use **fillNaBackward** together with **grouped_df’, ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ , 'data.frame'** to fill the NA value(s) ( both +6 and -6). Woud you mind providing a bit more info about it if it's at your convenience.

Comment: Hi. The tbl_df is similar to data.frame. It is a data structure from the dplyr package. I recommend you learn a bit about this package. To understand the fillNaBackward function, try to use c(NA,1,NA,NA,2,NA,3,NA,NA) as the vecTest and print the result of each line.

Comment: great, that's very helpful.